# Jar not found when executing class

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I'm working through a ANTLR (a language processing library) book and there are many examples that *should* be easy to compile using the command line.

Some information to get te problem:

`antlr-3.2.jar` contains the library classes. I added the `antlr-3.2.jar` to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (Windows 7) and when compiling the classes with `javac` everything works fine.
This is what i execute to compile my program:

```
javac Test.java ExprLexer.java ExprParser.java
```

`Test.java` contains my `main()`-method whereas `ExprLexer` and `ExprParser` are generated by ANTLR. All three classes use classes contained in the `antlr-3.2.jar`. But so far so good. As I just said, compiling works fine.

It's when I try to execute the `Test.class` that I get trouble. 
This is what I type:

```
java -cp ./ Test
```

When executing this, the interpreter tells me that he can't find the ANTLR-classes contained in the `antlr-3.2.jar`, altough I added an entry in the `CLASSPATH` variable.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/Cha
rStream
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.CharStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: Test.  Program will exit.
```

I'm using Windows 7 and Java 1.6_20. Can someone tell what is going on? Why will the interpreter not look in the jar-Archive I specified in the `CLASSPATH`?

I found some kind of workaroud. I copied the antlr-3.2.jar into the directory where the Test.class is located and then executed:

```
java -cp ./;antlr-3.2.jar Test
```

This worked out. But I don't want to type the jar-Archive everytime I execute my test programs. Is there a possibility to tell the interpreter that he should automatically look into the archive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm using Windows 7 and Java 1.6_20.
>   Can someone tell what is going on? Why
>   will the interpreter not look in the
>   jar-Archive I specified in the
>   CLASSPATH?

-cp on the commandline overrides the CLASSPATH variable.  There is no convenient way to do what you're trying to do.  I'd suggest creating an ant script, shell script, or shell alias if you don't want to type out the full classpath each time.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could put your Test application into its own jar file with a [manifest](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) that tells it to include antlr-3.2.jar in the classpath.

Comment: Sorry... i wanted to set the other post as answer, but i erroneaously set yours ... :)

Comment: @Simon: I saw that earlier and figured it was probably a mistake.  No harm, no foul. (I routinely post alternatives to answers that are correct.)